# Javascript export text file not recognizing \r\n in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am creating a text file for downloading from javascript using the following code:

```
var lineFeed = "\r\n";
var errorFile = "";

errorFile = "This is a test" + linefeed;
errorFile = errorFile + "Line 2";

var link = document.createElement("a");

link.download = 'test_errors.csv';
 link.href = 'data:application/text/html,' + errorFile;

 document.body.appendChild(link);
 link.click();

 // Cleanup the DOM
 document.body.removeChild(link);
 link = null;
```

It works as expected in Chrome, but the file that is downloaded from firefox doesn't return the line feed and carriage return.  Any idea if I need another escape character or something else?

Comment: i'm amazed that works in chrome. You should urlEncode the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the browsers treat whitespace differently.  base64 encoding is probably the safest but you can likely just use url encoding.

Instead of "\r\n" use "%0D%0A".  However, because you will likely have real data, and real data may have other characters that break things (like quote characters), I suggest you url encode the entire string:

```
link.href = 'data:application/text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(errorFile);
```

Comment: by the way, don't do both things. If you use encodeUriComponent, use "\r\n" in your string.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` - capitalize URI. Thanks for solution, I  met the same problem yesterday.