# Lost new-lines in JQuery text() in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, line-breaks

I have a DIV at the page which I want user to be able to download as a text file (this is a license key). This DIV has `\n` symbols which is correctly displayed using `white-space: pre;`. I use the code bellow to create temporary `<a>` link with DIV content and download it. This works fine in Chrome, but FireFox loose the new-line symbols and I get single-lined text.

```
downloadLicenseBtn = $("#download_license");
downloadLicenseBtn.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $temp = $("<a>");
    $(body).append($temp);
    $temp.attr({
        download: 'license.txt',
        href: "data:text/html," + $('.edd_sl_license_key').text() 
        })[0].click()
    $temp.remove();
});
```

I tried to use JQuery `html()` function instead of `text()`, tried to set up `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8`. No luck. :(

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/movs21/vy4ukdpr/

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks, but still the same result. :(

Comment: No, this is not an option. I don't need the html file as a result. I need .txt file with a vaild line-breaks.

Comment: I appreciate your dilemma, can you please provide a [example] in order to help with troubleshooting?

Comment: Oh, when I told you to replace the `<div>` with a `<pre>` tag, I didn't really tell you that you have to replace the literal `\n` with actual new lines by hitting the `return` key instead of adding `\n`. Hope that makes sense. That will def work.

Comment: @RandyCasburn First  - thank you for helping me. I added working example here https://jsfiddle.net/movs21/vy4ukdpr/ (StackOverflow hadn't allowed me to make download example here). There is a valid \n symbol inside. And everything ok with Chrome download. So it's FireFox who stole it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `encodeURIComponent( text )`, also it's possible to replace \r\n with %0D%0A: `replace('\n', '%0A', text)`.

Same question here: [Javascript export text file not recognizing \r\n in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372533/javascript-export-text-file-not-recognizing-r-n-in-firefox)